# Making a div wrap other div when using a hierachy with several layers

Tags: html, css

I've created following jsfiddle to visualize my issue: https://jsfiddle.net/ch8r1z4q/1/

[image]

The image shows a page layout I created. The yellow is a sidebar, the blue is a content wrapper, green mainelement and white subelement. The red is the wrapper for the whole thing, which is shown because the sidebar is cut off.

My issue here is I need to wrap the content in the blue wrapper, so the read section doesn't show, but the content instead has the width of the whole page. This is as to avoid waste of space in a several-page long scenario.

My issue lies in my hierachy structure:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="element">
            <div class="subelement">
                text text texttext text texttext text texttext text text
            </div>
            <div class="subelement">
                text text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text text
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            <div class="subelement">
                text text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text text
            </div>
            <div class="subelement">
                text text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            <div class="subelement">
                text text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text text
            </div>
            <div class="subelement">
                text text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <!-- Some other info -->
    </div>
</div>
```

If I only had the blue wrapper, I could simply put the sidebar into the wrapper as a float, and text would wrap. But I'm working with this element/subelement functionality, which doesn't provide that kind of freedom. Is there some flex solution, or other work around to achieve the desired result?

Elements and subelements are dynamic, so I'm afraid a hardcoded solution is unavailable.

Comment: give the div `display:inline-block` to prevent it from growing

Comment: So you would like to make the content fill the space under the side-bar right?

Comment: @ajobi Exactly, but the height of the sidebar isn't necessarily the same height at all times. The content inside the sidebar is also dynamic, so its height will change.

Comment: @ok34332 would something like this be possible? https://jsfiddle.net/zqr1h2a5/20/

Comment: @ajobi I don't seem to be able to get the same results on my environment, as your jfiddle. My content(the blue part) gets pushed down by the sidebar. Could this be a side-effect of me using input fields/textareas instead of generic  text?